# Get sum of amount records as each row is month and column is week using sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 1000 records in table `TBL_yearlyReport` with 2 columns:

- `Date_Val`  (eg '2016-12-25 23:48:40.360')
- `Amount` (eg 100, 1000 ,100 etc)

Sample data in `TBL_yearlyReport`

```
Date_Val    | Amount 
---------------------
2016-12-25  | 20000
2016-02-21  |  2000
```

I want to see a report on the basis of year, and I want to pass in a year as 2012 etc

Report must have a row for each month and columns returned will be 4 that are week1, week2, week3, week4

Each week's column value is the sum of current week amount

Here is what I have done so far:

```
DECLARE @LoopCounter INT = 1
DECLARE @MONTH INT = 1

BEGIN
     WHILE(@LoopCounter <= 100)
     BEGIN
         SET @LoopCounter  = @LoopCounter  + 1                 

         IF @MONTH = 1 
         BEGIN
             SELECT SUM(convert(INT, amount)) as JAN,  
                    @MONTH AS month  
             FROM TBL_yearlyReport 
             WHERE YEAR(Date_Val) = 2016 AND @MONTH = @MONTH 
         END

         IF @MONTH = 2 
         BEGIN
             SELECT SUM(convert(INT, amount)) as FEB,  
                    @MONTH AS month  
             FROM TBL_yearlyReport 
             WHERE YEAR(Date_Val) = 2016 AND @MONTH = @MONTH 
         END 

                 if @MONTH = 3 
                       begin
          SELECT sum(convert(int ,amount)) as FEB ,  @MONTH as month  FROM TBL_yearlyReport 
                    WHERE  YEAR(Date_Val) = 2016 and  @MONTH = @MONTH 
                end

             /////////so on continue to

                     if @MONTH = 12
                       begin
          SELECT sum(convert(int ,amount)) as FEB ,  @MONTH as month  FROM TBL_yearlyReport 
                    WHERE  YEAR(Date_Val) = 2016 and  @MONTH = @MONTH                     
                end    

                if @MONTH = 12
                begin
                   break
                end  
                 SET @MONTH   = @MONTH  + 1  
                end    END
```

Now the problem is how to get all ids that are between month so that use BETWEEN to sum amount?

How to get amount sum on weekly basis of each month like

```
     week1   |    week2   |  week3   | week4

      jan  
      feb
      march 
      june
```

etc

I want to do that to to get sum of amount on a weekly basis if I have their ids

```
SELECT SUM(convert(INT, amount)) ah  
FROM TBL_yearlyReport 
WHERE YEAR(Date_Val) = 2016  
  AND id between 1 and 100
```

Output should be:

```
SELECT @WEEK1, @WEEK2, @WEEK3, @WEEK4 
FROM TBL_yearlyReport 
WHERE Date_Val BETWEEN @startWEEKDATE AND @EndWEEKDATE
```

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Comment: Please define "week 1" for a month. The 1-7th of every month? What should in that case happen to the 29th and up? Thrown away?

Comment: GLOBAL TECH, are you inventing `group by`?

Comment: This is classic pivot query territory. See [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) for an introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose weeks numeration needed like this:

[image: weeks numeration]

We can take week number like 11, divide it by 4 and get 2,75. Then we take 75 and see that it equals to 3rd week. In that way we convert all the week nums.
Then you can use cte + pivot:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT MONTH(Date_Val) as [MonthNum],
       DATENAME(month,Date_Val) as [Month],
       DATEPART(week,Date_Val) as [ActualWeekNum],
       FLOOR((CAST(DATEPART(week,Date_Val) as decimal(5,2))/4- FLOOR(CAST(DATEPART(week,Date_Val) as decimal(5,2))/4))*100) as [Week],
       Amount as [Amount]
FROM  TBL_yearlyReport
WHERE  YEAR(Date_Val) = 2012
)

SELECT [Month],Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4
FROM
(
SELECT [MonthNum],
       [Month],
       CASE WHEN [Week] = 25 THEN 'Week1' 
            WHEN [Week] = 50 THEN 'Week2'
            WHEN [Week] = 75 THEN 'Week3' 
            WHEN [Week] = 0  THEN 'Week4'
            ELSE NULL
            END as [Week],
       Amount 
FROM cte
) d
pivot
(
SUM(Amount) for [WEEK] in (Week1,Week2,Week3,Week4)
) piv
ORDER BY [MonthNum];
```

Results are:

```
    Month                          Week1       Week2       Week3       Week4
------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
January                        1995        4798        5280        4500
February                       6102        4283        4039        4519
March                          7445        2616        5701        5977
April                          4991        5624        4823        4901
May                            3826        5858        1970        3703
June                           3461        3950        4208        1707
July                           2970        2469        5217        2861
August                         2536        2535        4887        2210
September                      2352        2721        4232        3165
October                        2876        3044        4702        7160
November                       3183        3158        4509        5507
December                       3666        3509        3276        3257
```

Comment: No column name was specified for column 5 of 'cte'.  only tell me

Comment: I have changed the answer. Try now. I used temp table named `#TBL_yearlyReport` with fields `Date_Val datetime, Amount int`.

Comment: why used that 'decimal(5,2))/4-'

Comment: Because if I just divide `11` by `4` I got `2` if `11` and `4` are `integer`. And if I cast to decimal I get `2.750000`.

Comment: i want the final amount sum in nvarchar(max) because the answer is out of range then integer value so where to use Convert(nvarchar , sum(amount) ) it not works i have 1 million record thats why

Comment: In 'cte' part you can 'CAST(Amount as bigint) as Amount'. '(nvarchar(max), sum(Amount)' will not help, because Amount is 'integer' and 'sum' function can't convert data types of passed values. And also 'sum' cannot work with nvarchar data type.

Comment: And I found 1 issue in my answer, if month consist of 5 or 6 weeks, it gives correct sum for month, but not correct for few weeks. For example 1-7 days 1st week, 8-14 2nd week, 15-21 3rd, 22-28 4th, 29-31 5th, fifth will be counted as 1st and so sum for first week will be for 1-7 and 28-31 days.

Comment: so will set criteria using ceil also i am thinking other options too wait

Comment: or set criteria for dates only 29 to 31 set them to previous week becuase we are calculating monthly and at 1 this become 25 so next week starts you are doing right 5th extra days joined with previous i am lil close wait